# Proving that when 2 r.v. become similar, the joint prob. they are equal and greater than some other increases

Tags: probability, random-variables

Think of 3 r.v., $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, coming from possibly different and unknown discrete distributions. In case it is determined that $P(X \geq Y)>P(Y \geq X)$ and $P(X \geq Z)>P(Z \geq X)$ and $P(Y \geq Z)>P(Z \geq Y)$ and that $P(X=Y)>0$, $P(X=Z)>0$, $P(Y=Z)>0$.

Is it possible to show formally that, regardless of the distribution of each variable, as $X$ and $Y$ become more similar, the probabilities $P(X=Y, X\geq Z)$ and $P(X=Y, Y\geq Z)$ increase?

EDIT: I added the word "discrete" before "distributions", which should have been there from the beginning. And after prompted by @delivery101, I also added the information that we know $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ **can** be equal.

Answer (score 0):

No, think e.g. about the event that $X, Y$ and $Z$ are continuous, then $\mathbb{P}(X= Y, X \geq Z) = 0$ and is therefore not increasing.

In case they are discrete, your statement (if I understand it correctly) does not hold either. You can e.g. let $X = aY$ for $a > 1$. Then it holds that $1 = \mathbb{P}(X \geq Y) > \mathbb{P}(Y \geq X)= 0$, but $\mathbb{P}(X = Y, X \geq Z) = 0$ and therefore not increasing (as even if '$X$ and $Y$ become more similar', taking $a$ closer to 1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok, in that case by construction $X$ cannot be equal to $Y$ because $a > 1$. What if we add the requirement that they can be equal? That is, in your example, we establish $X = aY$ for $a \geq 1$?

Comment: In that case ($a = 1$) $\mathbb{P}(X \geq Y) > \mathbb{P}(Y \geq X)$ does not hold..